# Scalable Reward Distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, uniform-distribution

Staking/Reward model:

Assets:

1. non-fungible token (an NFT asset)
2. fungible token (a digital coin)

Problem statement:

We need to create a model for an efficient NFT staking/reward model. An investor will buy a non-fungible token as an asset. If they plan to Hold it for a longer period of time they can Stake it to get rewards against it (I guess it equates to a fixed deposit in traditional banking).

We will have a stacking pool where we will deposit % of earnings from NFT secondary sales. When a participant stakes their NFT's we allocate fungible tokens as an intermediary reward. The amount each participant gets from the pool depends on the fungible token accumulated. (Not sure if this intermediary token is even required in this solution)

Due to high network transaction fees, we can not push the reward payments to each participant and have to follow a pull model where the participant draws their rewards or withdraws NFT staking when they desire.

Now the main issue is coming up with a mathematical algorithm to accomplish this. There seem to be many factors that come into play to determine a scalable reward system like

- The price of NFT at which the participant stakes the NFT.
- Price change of the NFT along the course of the staking period (inflation/deflation).
- Amount of time it is staked for.
- Number of NFT's one has staked.
- Compounding affect.

What can be the best possible way to make a mathematical formula to determine a scalable reward Distribution system here?

Comment: Since you evidently mean to refer to _probability_ distributions and not generalized-function distributions, I took the liberty to modify the tag.

Comment: Let's say a participant "A" wants to stake 2 his/her NFT in the Staking pool where we have let's say 50 already participants staked their NFTs (Total sum of NFTs in pool = Si).
We can get the following information
Ts= Total time of Staking for a participant
Sn = Total number of NFT staked by a participant
Si = Total stacked NFT in the pool
Rt = Total reward in the pool
Suppose we have 50 participants utilizing staking. How can we find the % of the reward for a particular participant in a particular instant of time? I know first, we have to check "Rt !<= 0" :)